# 'Debug.apk' installed through cordova,I can not remove it

Tags: android, cordova, uninstallation

Goodmorning everyone,
I'd better explain what I meant in the title,i've created an app through ionic/cordova. I used the command: " ionic cordova run android --device --verbose" to launch debug.apk on the device, connected to the pc.

Now the problem:

When I try to uninstall it, it is deleted, but going into 'Application management' i still see the app with the phrase: "not installed"(=Non installato).

device: samsung sm-t335 galaxy tab 4

I am going crazy,can someone help me ?

Sorry for my English

thank you all :)

[The image with the phrase "not installed" (=Non installato)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrJIe.jpg)

Comment: Tried restarting your device?

Comment: Already restarted 6/7 times, Cleaning with 'ccleaner'.... @SurajS

Comment: Is your phone rooted? If so, you can try removing it by using root uninstaller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have multiple users for your device, the app may be installed for all users and the entry may be ***persistent***. 
Try this

Settings -> Apps -> select your app tap on menu button (3 dots) -> Uninstall for all users

Or  this

Open each account and uninstall the app from there.